# HTML code 'classes' identifier selector wont work for me

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select classes in my html in my CSS, but it is not seeing the class (i can select list elements and it works but selecting class is not working)

I use Webstorm 9, maybe they havent implemented classes yet?

```css
.contact {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.contact a {
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.contact li.phone a {
  background-image: url('../phone.png')
}
.contact li.mail a {
  background-image: url('../phone.png')
}
.contact li.twitter a {
  background-image: url('../phone.png')
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>Contact Details</h3>
  <ul class="contact">
    <li class="phone"><a href="tel:555-6425">555-6425</a></li>
    <li class="mail"><a href="mailto:moei@my.normandale.edu">moei@my.normandale.edu</a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="twitter.com">@ianmoe</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: If you inspect your markup, you'll see that all of your styles are applied to the giving element. Can you clarify what is the issue here?

Comment: from webstorm page **"WebStorm 9 brings a compelling range of new features. With the support for the most trending and powerful frameworks and libraries, new integrated tools and new features and improvements basically in every part of the IDE, WebStorm 9 is a superior update."** yea i doubt they didnt implement classes yet

Comment: 4 years is an awfully long time to not implement a feature that has been around for 18 years.

Comment: @BoltClock that feature will be a revolution in web development.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you missed a semi-colon(;) on css as well as check the url path of background-image,

Comment: maybe this WebStorm 9 is a syntax nazi

Answer (score -2):

For some reason you forgot a semi-colon after background-image url for .phone, .mail, and .twitter.

```
}
.contact li.phone a {
  background-image: url('../phone.png');
}
.contact li.mail a {
  background-image: url('../phone.png');
}
.contact li.twitter a {
  background-image: url('../phone.png');
}
```